# provide updates to a webapp via a bitbucket repo

Tags: php, git, version-control, bitbucket

I have created a simple web-application using **PHP**, **JS** etc.. My next step is to deploy it to eg. `liveserver.com`. I am sure that I will be providing a lot of additional features in the future and so I would like to know how this is generally done. I am pretty sure its a noob question so [I tried to google](https://www.google.com.np/?gws_rd=cr&ei=UkYqV5ecNIbluQSnpLngDQ#q=how%20to%20provide%20updates%20to%20a%20web%20application) it but nothing helpful came up.

Here is a rough idea on how I may do it. I would keep a local copy in **WAMP** and keep developing it and sync / push it to bitbucket. The question is : **How do I connect the updated bitbucket version to my liveserver.com**. I am keen to know how web-developers generally provide updates to their app users. Is there a general update mechanism they follow ? Is my idea of using a version control application wrong for this purpose ? How would you do it for a simple app like this  ?

A concise answer would suffice. It would be great if anyone could provide me helpful links or point me to right direction, further information etc. TIA.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Please point out whats wrong in my question and I will make the correction. Do you think it is a wrong topic, bad question or imperfect question, which one is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really asking two questions here:

1. How do I connect the updated bitbucket version to my liveserver.com?
2. I would like to know how this (syncing code between test environment and production environment) is generally done, best practices and stuff.

The first question is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243694/update-code-from-git-bitbucket-to-live-server). The latter, broader question is [touched on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639668/keeping-testing-and-production-server-environments-clean-in-sync-and-consisten) but I'd like to offer my personal thoughts as well.

You've mentioned you're using WAMP, whereas I'm coming from a LAMP environment. Regardless, I'm hoping you will find some additional usefulness in my answer as it may help lead you to a Windows-based equivalent solution.

**At home/work:**

I also use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and prefer it to github. I have [Git](https://git-scm.com/) installed for source control which allows me to push or pull any code between bitbucket and my local machine.

**On the go:**

I have [AWD IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd&hl=en) installed on my tablet which allows me FTP access to a production environment, and the non-free version also has [Git integration](https://androidwebdev.wordpress.com/how-to-work-with-version-control-systems/). Another great IDE is [Cloud 9](https://c9.io/); completely web-based and convenient if I don't have my tablet with me and need to use a public computer or laptop. Cloud 9 also supports Git.

**Syncing:**

Rather than push code from Bitbucket to my production server, I prefer to keep a mirror of my production server locally. I use a tool called [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) for this. I have a bash file setup on a cron job that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync
SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
RUSER=remoteUser
RHOST=remoteHost
RPATH=/remote/path/
LPATH=/local/path/mirror/

$RSYNC -av --no-p --delete -O -e $SSH $RUSER@$RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH
```

---

So basically, my primary workstation (which is where I do most of my work) is always in sync with the live server. Both the live server and Bitbucket can be updated away from home. Thanks to Git, I can see exactly what has been modified. It's also comforting to know my code exists in three different places for redundancy.

This is what I have found to be most convenient for me, but I would love to know how others do it.

Comment: The links were very helpful.Thanks for putting me on right path.